# iOS AutoLayout working with something wrong

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I add a `UIView` in `UIStoryboard` and bind it to a custom `UIView` class called testView,next, I create a `UIView` called circelView in textView in require init function ,then I crate two `UILabel` in circelView

**this is my step**

1. initialization the circelView
2. add AutoLayout to circelView
3. create two `UILabel` and add them to circelView
4. add AutoLayout to two `UILabel`

then I run the app, I can find the subView in current position , But I can not find the two `UILabel` in screen ,what happen?

this is my code :

```
 required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        circelView = UIView()
        self.addSubview(circelView)
        circelView.snp_makeConstraints(closure: { (make) -> Void in
            make.size.equalTo(80)
            make.top.equalTo(self.snp_top)
            make.right.equalTo(self.snp_right)
        })



        titleLabel = UILabel()
        titleLabel.textColor = colorffffff
        titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        titleLabel.font = font32
        titleLabel.text = "hello"
        titleLabel.numberOfLines = 1
        titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        circelView.addSubview(titleLabel)
        titleLabel.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.center.equalTo(circelView.snp_center)
        }



        detailLabel = UILabel()
        detailLabel.textColor = colorffffff
        detailLabel.font = font24
        detailLabel.text = "hello"
        titleLabel.numberOfLines = 1
        detailLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        detailLabel.addSubview(titleLabel)
        detailLabel.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.top.equalTo(titleLabel.snp_bottom).offset(3)
            make.centerX.equalTo(titleLabel.snp_centerX)
        }

    }
```

Comment: Watch your storyboard，do you have miss constraint warning?

Comment: @SolaWing everything is ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things could be causing this:

- How big is your font? If your font is too large, and your view is too small (80x80 in this case), the text may not be rendered.
- In Autolayout, it is optimal to have views have sizes based on their content, and not explicit (i.e. 80x80). By having your labels be pinned to their superview on all edges, you can have the size of your 'circelView' be dynamic to its content (the two labels). To maintain the 'circle' aspect of your 'circelView', you can constraint the height of your 'circelView' to be the same as its width.

At the end of the day, this needs more debugging. I advise examining the view hierarchy to see where your labels are. [Check out the documentation here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html)

Comment: font size :`UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16)`

Comment: Try setting the size of your circelView to be something larger, like 300x300. Then try opening up the visual debugger.

Comment: I have try , But I can not find the UILabel too @Christopher Kevin Howell

Answer (score 0):

Your labels have 0 width and height. You don't set their `frame` anywhere in this code, and the constraints which apply to them relate only to their position, no size can be determined from them. You either need to Specify their `frame` or add constraints from which it could be determined by layouting engine.

Comment: The size can be determined for them based on their content.

You can verify this by creating a UILabel, adding it as as subview of a UIViewController's view, setting the text to "FOOBAR", and constraining it's position to be in the middle of a view. 

It'll be visible and have a frame that fits its content.

Comment: Well, touche. Have you tried debugging with visual debugger? Or calling `sizeToFit()` on these labels?

Comment: I have found cases where if you don't set proper width/height constraints, the width and height will be 0. Always a safe practice

Comment: If you have set up your constraints correctly, the intrinsic content size of the label will always give it a frame. In your case, you may have had another view compressing the label, in which case you would need to set the content compression / hugging priorities on the label and/or other views.

By setting height/width constraints on your views, you explicitly constrain the usefulness of whatever you have made. If I changed the font size of a UILabel in my case, the layout would adapt. In your case, you would need to go through and change the height/width constraints again.